# How to prevent Outlook from receiving multiple copies of the same email

Tags: home-networking, microsoft-outlook-2003, email, duplicate

This question might be asked already, but it's different from [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/16095/outlook-is-starting-to-receive-and-send-mails-in-duplicate-and-triplicate).

My boss has Outlook 2003, when he synchronize his emails while connecting through the local server (using Exchange I guess) he gets his emails normally.

Once he is outside (not connection to our LAN) he gets each email duplicated 3 or 4 times.

Does anyone experienced this before? and how can we fix this?

Please no links to FAQ pages. For info, we are using Kaspersky anti virus and Windows 2003 server, with windows XP clients.

**[Update]**

Actually we have a bunch of 5 or 6 email accounts on Outlook, and only one of them recieve duplicated copies of the same email, all the others are cool. Further more all these email are using the sae service, Gmail for example.

**[Update 2]**

I just found out that Outlook is configured to remove emails from the server already, also, some emails exceeds 5 copies!

Thank you

Comment: How is he connecting to your Exchange server when he's outside the LAN? Do you have a VPN he's connecting to with his laptop? Is he going into Outlook Web Access? Is he using the same machine he uses in the office? Does anyone else have access to his mail box, are they likely to be doing anything that modifies the mails, housekeeping, tidying, replying etc?

Comment: An approach to [prevent receiving multiple copies of the same email in outlook](http://www.techtopeace.com/2011/11/multiple-copies-of-same-email-in.html).

Answer (score 1):

Do all the e-mails turn up at the same time or do they arrive one at a time when he does a send/receive?

If so it could be that the e-mails are being left on the server and not marked as being delivered correctly.

Comment: no, just recieved email gets duplicates, and the email is sent just once, no duplicate destinations in the to or cc list

Comment: Woehoe what a team we make ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I have six email accounts and went to the account that was giving my five copies. I clicked test and it would keep sending me five tests. The only thing I changed was how I would like the account to be referred as, in 'more settings'. I changed the name and now I only get one email when I click test.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you also have a webmail version, if not try to see if the problem occurs in Thunderbird as well (or any other email client).

That way we can determine more precisely where the problem might be.

Based on the fact the problem doesn't occur when he's on your corperate network leads me to believe it's not what ChrisF suggested, since than he should also receive duplicates when at work.

He should also try to sent himself a test message when inside and outside the network by using Outlook's test mail in the account settings. If even his own emails are duplicated, then it must be what ChrisF suggests in his update. The server doesn't get notified that Outlook received the message.

[This website describes the problem](http://support.netfirms.com/idx.php/36/720/EMAIL/article/How-do-I-prevent-receiving-multiple-copies-of-the-same-email-message.html) your most likely seeing. Though I dislike his suggestion of pulling down the email and removing it from the server, since that would screw you up if you ever loose the local copy...

Comment: @Ivo - indeed. I've updated my answer already

Comment: He's probably not using POP or IMAP. Most likely if they are on Exchange and Outlook they are using the Exchange connector built into Outlook.

Comment: Deleted that part :)

Comment: yes, removing email from the server is not an option at all for us